# Natural isomorphism on homology implies natural chain homotopy equivalence?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $F,G: C \to \mathrm{Ch}(\mathbb{Z}\textrm{-free})$ be two functors, where $C$ is an arbitrary category and $\mathrm{Ch}(\mathbb{Z}-free)$ is the category of chain complexes of free abelian groups.

If $F_\ast, G_\ast: C \to H_n(\mathrm{Ch}(\mathbb{Z}\textrm{-free}))$ (taking the n-th homology) are natural isomorphic for every $n$, I know that for every $X \in C$ the complexes $F(X)$ and $G(X)$ are chain homotopy equivalent (this is false for modules in general, but true for $\mathbb{Z}$).

Can I assume, that the chain homotopy equivalences are natural too?